# Override specific docker-compose values with no value via file composition

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my project I have a series of docker-compose yml files. I run my application as such `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.ci.yml up -d`.

docker-compose.yml

```
db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    ...
ui:
    container_name: ui
    image: flask
```

docker-compose.ci.yml

```
db:
    image: db:$BUILD_NUM
ui:
    image: ui:$BUILD_NUM
```

Is there a way for me to override the container name (or any service property) that is defined in the base file with a blank value? In my case, I want the ci container name to be randomly generated. I don't want to remove the container name from the base yml file.